# What's the purpose? Strange login attemps "sshd[***] Received disconnect from **.**.**.**: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]"

Tags: ssh, brute-force

I've seen something like:

```
sshd[***]: Invalid user oracle from **.**.**.**                          // 1st line
sshd[***]: input_userauth_request: invalid user oracle [preauth]         // 2nd line
sshd[***]: Received disconnect from **.**.**.**: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]   // 3rd line
```

and I know that's someone tries to log into my server, but what does it mean when there's only the 3rd line repeating over and over again for, like, 3000+ times?

I mean, like this (there's no `Invalid user` or `input_userauth_request`):

```
sshd[***]: Received disconnect from **.**.**.**: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
sshd[***]: Received disconnect from **.**.**.**: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
sshd[***]: Received disconnect from **.**.**.**: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

What's the *purpose* of doing so, what's he trying to do since it's *"disconnect"* instead of trying to login?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This error rises from a fatal error in the authentication process (see `monitor.c` of OpenSSH versions 6.1p1+).

It is likely that the attacker is using some custom code to brute-force the server which is ending up in malformed authentication requests being sent, resulting in the server killing the connection. So from the code it appears they are in fact trying to login, but the server doesn't like how they're attempting that.

As such, these log entries aren't anything to worry about unless you think you are likely to be a targeted victim for any reason (in which case you should be taking extra precautions such as refusing password-based logins).

In any case, I suggest you install the simple `fail2ban` program if you haven't already which will significantly hinder cookie-cutter brute-force authentication attempts.

Comment: Thx. So, since I'm using fail2ban and using SSH key only, my server is safe, right? ;)

Comment: Over what period of time are you getting these 3,000+ log entries? Worth investigating that fail2ban is working effectively. There is a delay before it acts but it's possible it doesn't regard this specific log-line as an issue, if it's not just incorrectly setup.

Comment: fail2ban is up and running, and the reason those entries appeared in the log is because the default fail2ban rules just ignored them and took no action( yes I think you are right that *it doesn't regard this specific log-line as an issue*). I added some regex to sshd-ddos.conf and now, the log looks fine. :)

Comment: Still, felt a bit weird that since the default fail2ban rule doesn't regard this as an issue, then those attempts should be not so dangerous...then...what's the point of doing this kind of attack...

Comment: My gut feeling is the authors of the provided rules expected the associated log entries that you mentioned and so only included those. Re the point of this attack, I do think that the attack is not effective and it's a flaw in their attack versus your specific SSH server, making it effective only as a possible DoS rather than a risk of compromise. It might be an idea to enable debug logging and watch it for a few days to see if the same attack is launched, then spot what specifically they're trying although I can't guarantee even debug logging would capture anything interesting.

Comment: I enabled debug logging and waited for a while, but it seems that IP had already lost his interests on my server :)

Comment: +1 - saw this on my EC2 instance (trying to learn about different logs) and I was curious about what it was - thanks for the answer

Comment: sshd gives a banner with version, e.g. `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2`. Perhaps the attackers are probing for particular vulnerable versions.  This article suggests the attackers might be looking for weak host keys generated by vulnerable versions of ssh: http://taint.org/2008/05/16/165301a.html

Comment: Could it be that these error come up *because* the server is set to key authentication only? So the attacker tries to authenticate using a password (disregarding the server message that asks for key authentication only) and the server "doesn't like how they're attempting that."?

Answer (score 1):

I use a laptop (running linux) somtimes with a 3G dongle (directly connected to the internet) and I get hundreds of these:

```
Oct 21 10:11:52 c4111um sshd[8912]: Failed password for invalid user hash from 203.195.182.30 port 36789 ssh2
Oct 21 10:11:53 c4111um sshd[8912]: Received disconnect from 203.195.182.30: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Oct 21 10:11:56 c4111um sshd[8914]: Invalid user admin from 203.195.182.30
Oct 21 10:11:56 c4111um sshd[8914]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Oct 21 10:11:56 c4111um sshd[8914]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 21 10:11:56 c4111um sshd[8914]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=203.195.182.3
```

http://www.infobyip.com/ip-203.195.182.30.html
(usually originates from our chums in China)

Comment: yeah, the IP that i'm talking about is from China also :(